# Dynamic amount of sequential HTTP requests in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, observable

This is my first question here, sorry if it isn't detailed enough.

I am looking to make a dynamic amount of requests sequentially (could be a lot) to get data,

I would need this data to be collected from each request and returned as a final observable at the end of the last request.

I have attempted to use `forkJoin` to combine the requests, although, this does not make each request sequentially and then also `concat`, which emits and observable after each request.

Comment: Hi, Please show some code to help us see what you've already tried

Comment: Do you know how many requests you'll need to make when you start, or is it possible that it might change while requests are being made?

Comment: @KurtHamilton Once you start, you will know how many requests you will need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to:

- Make an arbitrary number of sequential HTTP requests (based on some array, I assume)
- Return an array of results

I would use `concat` in conjunction with `toArray` here. `concat` will run the requests sequentially, and `toArray` will emit an array when all responses are available.

```js
// some dynamic array
const source = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];

const observables = source.map(x => this.http.get('some url'));
concat(
  ...observables
).pipe(
  toArray()
).subscribe(responses => {
  console.log(responses);
  // array of results
});
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s1fdxj

Comment: you can use also toArray: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/toarray

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks. I knew there would be a better implementation